# Python program to calculate grades using a main function

Tags: python

I am trying to write a program that calculates a student's grades based on given grade weights for 5 different assignment types (Exam 1, Exam 2, Exam 3, Homework, and Final). I am having troubling with the first part of the program where I have to define a function that queries the user for a grade and validates if it is correct.

When I try to run the code I keep getting a name error saying "assignment_name is not defined". I have also tried to create a for loop or just multiple while statements.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wLhOJ.png)

Comment: post code inside ``` instead of an image

Comment: we won't be able to help you if you post questions about one version of your code and post code of another. stick to one problem at a time please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why you are inputting assignment_name into the function and then defining assignment_name inside the function, but here is maybe a solution to your problem, if you are trying to get a prompt to enter a grade for the 5 assignments you provided. This will iterate through each of the exams, the homework, and the final, asking for a grade for each.

```
def get_grade():
    grades = []
    assignment_name = ["Exam 1", "Exam 2", "Exam 3", "Homework", "Final"] # list of assignments for grades to be entered in
    for assignment in assignment_name: # creates loop, asking for grade in each assignment
        grade = int(input("What is your grade for %s? " % assignment))
        while grade < 0 or grade > 100:
            print("Grade must be a number between 0 and 100")
            grade = int(input("What is your grade for %s? " % assignment)) # asks for new input if previous was not in range
        grades.append(grade) # adds grade to list of grades
    return grades # prints out list of grades, with index 0 being Exam 1 and 4 being Final
```

If I understand your question wrong, please clarify it. For future reference, clarity is essential in asking questions so everybody can understand it and help in the best way possible.

Answer (score 1):

Just a heads up, it's super helpful to post your code inside of code blocks as well as the stack trace, if available.

##### Down to Business!

Based the picture you've provided, we're working with:

```
def get_grade(assignment_name):
    assignment_name = "Exam 1", "Exam 2", "Exam 3", "Homework", "Final"
    assignment = int(input("What is your grade for", assignment_name))
    while assignment < 0 or assignment > 100:
        print("Grade must be number between 0 and 100")
```

A few things that jump out at me:

1. `assignment_name` is an argument to your function, but then is immediately overwritten by a local variable by the same name.
2. `assignment = int(input("What is your grade for", assignment_name))` has a few things going on.

   - The variable name "assignment" is misleading here. I think something like "grade" or "grade_input" would be more readable since we're trying to capture an assignment grade from the user rather than an actual assignment.
   - The input() function only takes one argument. See more [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input)
3. Your while statement expression is good, but the logic it's executing is going to get stuck in an infinite loop because you don't have a base case for exiting the loop.

##### Another Take

To clean up the function, I would write something like:

```
def get_assignment_grade_input(assignment_name):
    while True:
        grade_input = int(input(f"What is your grade for {assignment_name}?"))
        if 0 <= grade_input <= 100:
            return grade_input
        else:
            print("Invalid grade. Grade must be between 0 and 100.")
            continue
```

This function takes an assignment name as an input and will prompt the user for the grade associated with the given assignment name. If the grade doesn't meet the acceptable criteria, we'll prompt the user for an acceptable grade input. *Note: It's probably not the best idea to infinitely prompt the user for a new grade if it's consistently unacceptable, but this should do to get the point across!*

Finally, if we are given an acceptable grade, our function will exit the loop by returning the grade to the caller.